# How do you breed a Steel dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

Seems the new dragons are coming fast and furious as I am trying to keep up.

What are the successful combinations in order to obtain a Steel Dragon? I would assume Metal with some form of hybrid (Bronze maybe?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just breed a Metal dragon and a Cold dragon for a [Steel Dragon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Steel_Dragon), though you might get a [Mine Dragon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Mine_Dragon) as well. It's best if you *don't* use hybrid dragons.

If you get a breeding/incubation time of 14 hours, you got a Steel dragon. If you get a time of 10 hours you got a Mine dragon instead.

Answer (score 1):

To get a steel dragon, you breed moon and sun dragons.

Answer (score 0):

You should breed Panlong and Rust dragons. (Both have to be level 10.)

Answer (score -1):

Metal and ice breed you well get 14 hour. Now I'm breeding the steel dragon.